# Passing form fields (...name="array1[]") to Javascript function and change value of other form fields (...name="array2[]")

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I have the following document (listed below) that times "Amount 1" by 2 (am1 * 2), and change the value in "Amount 2" to the result (executed by JavaScript).

Then the same form has the capability to add fields (Amount 1 & Amount 2) to the form.

I would like to have the same functionality (times "Amount 1" by 2 and change the value of "Amount 2") in the other "ADDED" fields.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var ct = 1;
function new_combi(){
          ct++;
          var div1 = document.createElement('div');
          div1.id = ct;
          // link to delete extended form elements
          var delLink = '<div style="text-align:right;margin-right:65px"><a href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">Del</a></div>';
          div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML + delLink;
          document.getElementById('combine').appendChild(div1);
}
// function to delete the newly added set of elements
function delIt(eleId){
          d = document;
          var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
          var parentEle = d.getElementById('combine');
          parentEle.removeChild(ele);
}

function calculate(){   
          am1 = document.form1["am1[]"].value;
          total = am1*2;
          document.form1["am2[]"].value = total;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<div id="combine">
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%" valign="top">Amount 1</td>
      <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="am1[]" onchange="calculate()"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">Amount 2</td>
      <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="am2[]" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<p id="addnew">
          <a href="javascript:new_combi()">Add Combination</a>
</p>
</form>
<!-- Template to add-->
<div id="amount" style="display:none">
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%" valign="top">Amount 1</td>
      <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="am1[]" onchange="calculate()"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">Amount 2</td>
      <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="am2[]" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something for you. Hope this will work.

I just given an attribute `id=1` to your to your `div` inside `div#combine`.

```
<div id="1">
```

I changed your calculate function.

```
function calculate(){
  for (var i = 1; i <= ct; i++) {
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById(i);
    var am1 = currentDiv.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    var total = am1 * 2;
    currentDiv.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = total;
  };
}
```

Try and let me know if any problem is there, because I changed your implementation logic.

Comment: Brilliant, working perfectly! Thank you very much! :D

Comment: change :) If input[1] is changed (manually after calculation), and another combination is added - the "changed value" is reverted back to the calculation (changed data is reset). Is there a way I could keep the changed values?